# Performance of multi threaded read using Ormlite on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, sqlite, ormlite

I want to read two different tables (DAOs) with Sqlite on Android using Ormlite. Each table has more than 10.000 rows.

I am aware that I should use only one connection via `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);`. No problem.

My question is, will it be quicker, if I use two parallel threads to read the two tables or is the database not meant for parallel access with regards to performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase` has its own locking internally to make it thread safe and prevent concurrent access. Previously you could call [`setLockingEnabled(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLockingEnabled%28boolean%29) to affect this, but it's deprecated since API 16. However, since API 11 you can call [`enableWriteAheadLogging()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()), which enables parallel execution of queries from multiple threads on the same database. You should call this as early as possible, so either in [`onConfigure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) (API 16+) or [`onOpen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onOpen(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)).

Comment: It may, you'll have to try it.